# Force R base plot to end on tick mark

Tags: r, plot

The powers that be demand that plots end on tick marks.  I know it can be done in ggplot with `expand = c(0,0)`, but how can I do it using only base R?

Comment: What kind of plot? Can you `dput` your data?

Comment: do you mean that the plotting area should finish exactly at the limits of the data and this should be  marked by a labelled tick mark at that same value? thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `xaxs` and `yaxs` options,e.g.:

```
plot(1:3,1:3,xaxs='r',yaxs='r')
```

`?par` says:

> xaxs The style of axis interval calculation to be used for the x-axis.
>   Possible values are "r", "i", "e", "s", "d". The styles are generally
>   controlled by the range of data or xlim, if given. Style "r" (regular)
>   first extends the data range by 4 percent at each end and then finds
>   an axis with pretty labels that fits within the extended range. Style
>   "i" (internal) just finds an axis with pretty labels that fits within
>   the original data range. Style "s" (standard) finds an axis with
>   pretty labels within which the original data range fits. Style "e"
>   (extended) is like style "s", except that it is also ensures that
>   there is room for plotting symbols within the bounding box. Style "d"
>   (direct) specifies that the current axis should be used on subsequent
>   plots. (Only "r" and "i" styles have been implemented in R.)

Comment: Perfect! 'plot(1:3, 1:3, xaxs = 'i', yaxs = 'i')' did exactly what I needed.

Comment: I'm confused by `(Only "r" and "i" styles have been implemented in R.)`. What's the point of describing values `"s"`, `"e"` and `"d"` if they are not implemented? I would expect that old good `par` has a mature documenation that matches with the functionality.